# How can i store/show pictures of the contacts saved in a contacts list in SP 2010?

Tags: contacts

In have a Contacts list in my SharePoint 2010 environment. I want to store/show pictures of the contacts saved in this list.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a person/group field to your list of contacts, you can set the display to Name(with picture) to show the picture from the user's profile automatically.

There is alos the possibility of adding a hyperlink column to the list to point to an image of the user so it's displayed inline.

Another alternative is to just upload the image of the user as an attachment to the contact.

Comment: Thanks PirateEric. But, can we achieve same if i don't have any person/group field in my list.

Comment: updated answer to include a few other options.